# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: runs\train\exp3 is not a directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, yolov5

I followed a tutorial on Yolov5,tutor fine tuned it on own data,I wanted to train it with my own data. I ran this command

```
!cd yolov5 && python train.py --img 320 --batch 16 --epochs 500 --data dataset.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --workers 2
```

It creates a folder in runs everytime I run it,I have no idea how to fix it.

```
github: up to date with https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5 
YOLOv5  v7.0-210-gdd10481 Python-3.11.3 torch-2.0.1+cu118 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Laptop GPU, 16384MiB)

hyperparameters: lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=0.05, cls=0.5, cls_pw=1.0, obj=1.0, obj_pw=1.0, iou_t=0.2, anchor_t=4.0, fl_gamma=0.0, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0
Comet: run 'pip install comet_ml' to automatically track and visualize YOLOv5  runs in Comet
TensorBoard: Start with 'tensorboard --logdir runs\train', view at http://localhost:6006/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Masaüstü\yolo\yolov5\train.py", line 647, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Masaüstü\yolo\yolov5\train.py", line 536, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
  File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Masaüstü\yolo\yolov5\train.py", line 101, in train
    loggers = Loggers(save_dir, weights, opt, hyp, LOGGER)  # loggers instance
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OneDrive\Masaüstü\yolo\yolov5\utils\loggers\__init__.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.tb = SummaryWriter(str(s))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 247, in __init__
    self._get_file_writer()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 277, in _get_file_writer
    self.file_writer = FileWriter(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.event_writer = EventFileWriter(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorboard\summary\writer\event_file_writer.py", line 72, in __init__
    tf.io.gfile.makedirs(logdir)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 513, in recursive_create_dir_v2
    _pywrap_file_io.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: runs\train\exp3 is not a directory
```

also, my dataset.yaml file looks like this

````
path: data
train: data/images/
val: data/images/

nc: 17
names: [ "dog","person","cat","tv","car","meatballs","marinara sauce","tomato soup",
"chicken noodle soup","french onion soup","chicken breast","ribs",
"pulled pork","hamburger","cavity","User","Sunglasses"] # User and Sunglasses are my own labels```
````

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a folder called `exp3` in `yolov5/runs/train` but not finding it there. This could be due to a few things.

- Do you already have another file named `exp3` in `yolov5/runs/train`?
- Are you running the CLI command from the yolov5 directory? Try running `pwd` or `!pwd` ("print working directory"). If it prints anything other than `yolov5`, then you need to switch working directories.